# Will this set up fry my components?

Tags: multirotor, quadcopters, building, compatibility

**Frame:** Carbon fiber 250mm
**Motors:** 2300Kv 2204
**Power board:** Matek built in BEC’s 12V + 5V
**FC:** CC3D
**ESCs:** HLGRC 30A opto (no BEC)
**Battery:** Turnigy Graphene 14V 75C 4S
**Receiver:** Turnigy iA6B

My question is, this is the first time I’ll be using the opto on a drone. How do I power the FC without frying it, seeing as how there are no BECs on the ESCs?

Answer (score 4):

The Matek PDB has a 5V regulator and this can be used to power the fc.

Just wire the PDB to one of the unused ESC plugs on the FC. The FC has solder pads for 6 ESCs (right on the picture) and for a quad you usually only need 4. So the connectors 1-4 are used for the escs and you can use 5 or 6 for the PDB.

The center pin (with + above) is 5V and the outer pin is ground (- above). Connect these two pads to the according pads on the PDB.

[image: cc3d pinout]

Answer (score 1):

Does your Matek power board have a 5V output? If it does have built in BECs, as your post suggests, you could be able to use those.

```
                                     ┌─────────────────────────┐
                                     │       ┌─────────────────┼┐
                                  ╔══╧══╗ ╔══╧══╗              ││
                                  ║ ESC ║ ║ ESC ║              ││
                                  ╚══╤══╝ ╚══╤══╝              ││
    ╔═══════════════╗  ╭───────╮  ╔══╧═══════╧══╗  ╭──────╮  ╔═╧╧═╗
    ║ LiPo Battery  ╟──┤  14V  ├──╢ Power Board ╟──┤  5V  ├──╢ FC ║
    ╚═══════════════╝  ╰───────╯  ╚══╤═══════╤══╝  ╰──────╯  ╚═╤╤═╝ 
                                  ╔══╧══╗ ╔══╧══╗              ││
                                  ║ ESC ║ ║ ESC ║              ││
                                  ╚══╤══╝ ╚══╤══╝              ││
                                     │       └─────────────────┼┘
                                     └─────────────────────────┘
```